# Custom checkbox : add cross icon on uncheck using css?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I've been searching a while here and there and can't seem to find a way to stylize the uncheck state of a checkbox. I can change the background to red, but I need to add a cross as well, is it possible in css?

[image]

[image]

Here is my code and thanks for any help

```css
/* The customcheck */
.customcheck {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  right: 10px;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.customcheck input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.customcheck:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.customcheck input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #02cf32;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.customcheck input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.customcheck .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<label class="customcheck">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used :pseudo element to add a cross icon

```css
.customcheck {
  position: relative;
}

.customcheck input {
  display: none;
}

.customcheck input~.checkmark {
  background: #ee0b0b;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.customcheck input~.checkmark:after,
.customcheck input~.checkmark:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  left: 12px;
  top: 4px;
}

.customcheck input~.checkmark:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.customcheck input~.checkmark:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.customcheck input:checked~.checkmark {
  background: #3d8a00;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customcheck input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: none;
}

.customcheck input:checked~.checkmark:before {
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 6px;
  top: 2px;
  left: 9px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  height: 13px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<label class="customcheck">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span> Label Text
</label>
```

Comment: what if a label text is added. Then the checkbox will sit on top of the label

Comment: Never use `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` for an input (when there's a necessity to replace it with a custom element)

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox with a cross when unchecked, and a tick when checked

```css
* {
    background-color: #555;
    color: #eee;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    appearance: none;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
    background-color: red;
    transition: 250ms;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #222;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:before {
    content: "✖";
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
    content: "✔";
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background-color: green;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #222;
}
```

```html
Some Property: 
<input type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score -2):

jep. Here is some quick code. You can always make it more beatiful. But this is the concept

```
<input class="customcheckInput" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<label class="customcheck"></label>

.customcheck {
position: relative;
padding-left: 30px;
}
.customcheck:before {
content: "";
display: block;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #000;
height: 20p;
width: 20px;
}

.customcheck:after {
content: "";
display: none;
position: absolute;
background: red;
height: 10p;
width: 10px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

.customcheckInput + .customcheck:after {
display: blocK;
}
```